# Strange freezing -- defective video card?

Tags: graphics-card, motherboard, freeze

I'm working on a system with an existing Windows installation but essentially brand new hardware. It's got a GA-H270M-D3H motherboard, 4 GB RAM, a CoolerMaster G750M and a GIGABYTE Windforce Radeon RX460 4GB, all newly purchased. It is *mostly* working, and I've got all the drivers from GIGABYTE's web site, the latest motherboard firmware, and also the latest Radeon Crimson drivers installed, but there's a strange lock-up that keeps happening.

I haven't figured out an exact trigger yet -- sometimes it happens when I am not obviously doing anything at all. Sometimes it happens when switching to/from a 3D accelerated application. When it happens, the screen is suddenly filled with a solid colour and the system is hard locked (except that I can turn Num Lock off -- not back on, but it does respond to the first press). I'm not 100% certain this is the case, but it really seems that the solid colour that fills the screen is whatever colour is in the top-left pixel -- sometimes the deep blue of the default Windows 10 background, sometimes white from Chrome's title bar, orange from the FurMark benchmark. I set the desktop background to red and one of the lockups filled the screen with red.

A few of the lockups have taken place while running the FurMark benchmark, because I wanted to stress the video card, see if it could more directly trigger the problem. It doesn't trigger it -- FurMark ran for 45 minutes straight before the last freeze, which happened about 0.5 seconds after I *closed* FurMark -- but it does mean I have some idea of the GPU temperature. I don't think it is overheating. At the time of the freeze, it was showing the GPU fan speed as 55% and the temperature as 68°C.

Could this indicate a defective video card? I'm no hardware expert but I do know that video cards have a "dot clock" that walks through the pixels in the framebuffer at exactly the right rate to send them down the wire to the monitor, and just speculating, it occurs to me that sending the same colour pixel for the entire frame perhaps suggests that the dot clock is somehow stopped or rendered ineffective. That's just my speculation, though, and I'm hoping someone else reading this will say, "Oh, yes, I know exactly what's causing that!"

Any thoughts?

Comment: Further information: Nothing appears in the Windows System Event Log, except for the facts that "The last shutdown's success status was false" and "The previous system shutdown was unexpected". When it freezes, the only way I have found to get it out of the frozen state is to power cycle it.

Comment: Follow-up: Took the video card out, ran the thing on onboard video, left Unigine Valley running at various quality levels for 6+ hours, repeatedly switched windows, no crash occurred. I'm about 95% sold on this being a hardware problem with the graphics card at this point.

Comment: have you figured out what was it .?

Comment: Oh man, this was ages ago now :-) I think we ended up asking the shop for a replacement video card, or possibly motherboard, but my memory is definitely fuzzy after 2 years.

Comment: well i run into similar problem, with rx580 and asrock board, regardless gpu load i'm getting hard freeze when card temperature reaches ~60C. as workaround I put fans to run at max, though it's not enough for ultimate tests. 75% sure it is motherboard, it's getting pretty hot below the card.

Comment: Even though the symptoms are similar, I'm not sure it's the same issue. My issue happened with no apparent trigger, including temperature. It would run a benchmark stably for 45+ minutes with the temperature pegged at 68°C and not freeze. Then I'd exit the benchmark and within a second _then_ it froze. But it didn't do it the next time when I tried to reproduce it. It was a crafty bugger!